# How to get the name of the first cookie in a JSP page using EL?

Tags: jsp, cookies, el

Using EL in a JSP page `${cookie[0].value.name}` this doesn't print anything, but if I just use `${cookie}`, this prints the list of cookies. How can I print only the name of the first one?

Answer (score 0):

The implicit EL variable `${cookie}` is essentially a `Map<String, Cookie>` where the cookie name is the key and the [`Cookie`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html) instance itself is the value.

It's thus not a `List`. You can't access map entries by an integer based index. A specific entry of this particular map can only be accessed by the cookie name. Below example assumes `foo` as cookie name.

```
${cookie.foo}
```

Its value can be obtained as below.

```
${cookie.foo.value}
```

You can access the first entry of a `Map<K,V>` in below clumsy way (not less clumsy than in "plain Java" though).

```
${cookie.entrySet().iterator().next()}
```

Its name can be printed as below, via map key.

```
${cookie.entrySet().iterator().next().key}
```

Or as `name` property of `Cookie` instance as map value.

```
${cookie.entrySet().iterator().next().value.name}
```

You only need to keep in mind that nothing in the Servlet specification guarantees the ordering of the cookie map. It might under the covers use a `HashMap` and then the ordering would be different from what you're seeing in request headers and even vary on every request.

Nonetheless, grabbing "the first" cookie apparently without knowing its name is fishy. This indicates a bigger design problem. If you know the cookie name, just use it directly.

```
${cookie.foo}
```

Otherwise you need to take a step back and reconsider the solution for the problem you tried to solve for which you likely incorrectly thought that this approach would be the right solution. On the other hand, perhaps you merely wanted to print the name=value pairs of all cookies for debugging purposes?

```
<c:forEach items="${cookie}" var="currentCookie">  
    Cookie name as map entry key: ${currentCookie.key}<br/>
    Cookie object as map entry value: ${currentCookie.value}<br/>
    Name property of Cookie object: ${currentCookie.value.name}<br/>
    Value property of Cookie object: ${currentCookie.value.value}<br/>
    <br/>
</c:forEach>
```

You can just find them in browser's builtin HTTP traffic monitor too. Press F12 in Chrome/FireFox23+/IE9+ and open tab *Network*.